# Rejecting an application/x-www-urlencoded call from Slack with AWS Api gateway if field doesn't match

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, slack

I have POST requests coming from Slack's outgoing webhooks, which are going through the API Gateway to an AWS Lambda function.
I want to filter requests with the API gateway before they ever make it to my lambda function, to reduce the number of times the lambda function will be called, for security purposes.

Technically, it doesn't matter where the call comes from, or where it's going.

The core of my problem is that I want to know how to filter/reject an API call with the AWS Api Gateway if a field doesn't match what I expect.

For example, consider this json.

```
{
  "body": "token=specificToken&someOtherField=someValue"
}
```

I want to reject the request if the token field doesn't match the expected "specificToken" value.

Comment: I don't see how reducing the number of invocations can significantly improve the security.

Comment: Say, a malicious user gets ahold of my api endpoint. They decide to attempt to send a ton of requests.
I'm now paying for each of those lambda function calls.

Comment: It reduces your cost, yes but not _significantly_ improving your security.

Comment: Using a custom authorizer will do that for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, REQUEST authorizer type does not support the request payload. Is this the only format Slack uses to pass authorization tokens? Or is that your choice?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom authorizer of the `REQUEST` type to do that. A `REQUEST`-type custom authorizer can use the request body for authorizing the request.

Reference: [Create an API Gateway Custom Authorizer Lambda Function](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html#api-gateway-custom-authorizer-lambda-function-create) (Scroll down to the `REQUEST` type)

Basically, you write another Lambda that serves as a *middleware* between your API Gateway. This custom authorizer will decide whether to allow the request or to return `Unauthorized` to API Gateway.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same requirement (verifying a request from slack with a lambda authorizer), and sadly the `REQUEST` type does *NOT* have access to the `body` of the request. Headers, path, querystring... but not body. This appears to be by design. See [Access POST Request body from Custom Authorizer Lambda Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47400447/access-post-request-body-from-custom-authorizer-lambda-function).

We experimented with a custom body mapping template to pull values out of the body and put them into headers, but the mapping is applied *after* authorisation so this does not work.

Finally, we decided to put our own token in the querystring of the webhook called by our slash command, and verify that instead, which is possible inside a `REQUEST` authorizer. Not as secure, but it works.