# Access POST Request body from Custom Authorizer Lambda Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I've got a custom authorizer lambda function in AWS configured for an API to another Lambda function with a POST resource.

The authorizer is setup as of type `Request`, not `Token`, because I am not using tokens in the Authorization header, and instead want to access form data that is being posted.

When I inspect the contents of the `event` parameter to my authorizer function, I do not see any of the original `POST` request body (form data). However, if I change my resource to a `GET`, I see the form data in the `queryStringParameters` as expected.

*(notice below that when the request is POST, the `queryStringParameters` is always an empty object)*

**Is there anyway to access the form data from the request in the function, when using a `POST` method?**

Here's an example of what the `event` parameter to the authorizer function will contain when using POST:

```
{
  type: 'REQUEST',
  methodArn: 'arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:********:********/dev/POST/receive',
  resource: '/receive',
  path: '/sms/receive',
  httpMethod: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: '*/*',
    'CloudFront-Viewer-Country': 'US',
    'CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto': 'https',
    'CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer': 'false',
    'CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer': 'false',
    'User-Agent': 'TwilioProxy/1.1',
    'X-Forwarded-Proto': 'https',
    'CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer': 'false',
    Host: 'api.myredactedcompany.io',
    'X-Forwarded-Port': '443',
    'X-Amzn-Trace-Id': 'Root=**************',
    Via: '1.1 ***************.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=259200',
    'X-Twilio-Signature': '***************************',
    'X-Amz-Cf-Id': '****************************',
    'X-Forwarded-For': '[redacted IP addresses]',
    'Content-Length': '492',
    'CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer': 'true',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },
  queryStringParameters: {},
  pathParameters: {},
  stageVariables: {},
  requestContext: {
    path: '/sms/receive',
    accountId: '************',
    resourceId: '*****',
    stage: 'dev',
    requestId: '5458adda-ce2c-11e7-ba08-b7e69bc7c01c',
    identity: {
      cognitoIdentityPoolId: null,
      accountId: null,
      cognitoIdentityId: null,
      caller: null,
      apiKey: '',
      sourceIp: '[redacted IP]',
      accessKey: null,
      cognitoAuthenticationType: null,
      cognitoAuthenticationProvider: null,
      userArn: null,
      userAgent: 'TwilioProxy/1.1',
      user: null
    },
    resourcePath: '/receive',
    httpMethod: 'POST',
    apiId: '*******'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47340143/8972418) to a similar question, it does not seem the body is provided to custom authorizers. Documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-lambda-authorizer-input.html) does not list a body parameter. I think perhaps the thinking is that the authorizer should rely on the route and headers rather than getting into the application-level body data.

Comment: Which is kinda silly if you think about it, since amazon's own auth mechanism requires full body content.  It would be really nice to be able to implement a signature-based authorizer for a little better security.

Comment: I agree that the body would be useful - especially if you need to validate a third party webhook signature, such as what's provided with Stripe webhooks.

Comment: Also fireblocks webhooks. We NEED the body.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to implement a signature-based authorizer, you can use a Lambda@Edge. It works with cloud front and you can intercept events in viewer request, origin request, origin response and viewer response.

Fields received:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-event-structure.html#request-event-fields-request

Be aware of the body size limitations, the body will be truncated if it exceeds the size limit.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-requirements-limits.html#lambda-at-the-edge-body-size-limits-lambda-at-edge